# method signature pass parameter as IEnumerable<T> or as List<T>

Tags: c#

The language I use is C#.

As I have read, it is better if a method of an object returns an enumerable type like a list, to state it its signature as bellow:

```
private IEnumerable<int> listOfNumbers()
{
   // here goes the code of the method
}
```

rather than

```
private List<int> listOfNumbers()
{
  //  here goes the code of the method
}
```

Let now that we want to pass as a parameter a list of objects of type A.

When we write

```
private IEnumerable<int> listOfNumbers(List<A> list)
{
  // here goes the code of the method
}
```

it is easier to access the elements of the list and do any calculations with them rather than writing

```
private IEnumerable<int> listOfNumbers(IEnumerable<A> list)
{
    // here goes the code of the method.
}
```

In the second case, in order to access the elements of the list, that implements the interface IEnumerable, we should convert the list to a List, inside the code of the method.

I am bit confused about the best way to pass as a parameter a type tha implements the IEnumerable interface. What's the best approach between the above two? Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Keep abstracting the definition until you notice that you don't have the required methods available anymore. Then go one spot back and take the abstraction at that point.

Comment: it's better because it allows to use any type implementing `IEnumerable<A>` (including `List<A>`, `A[]`, ...) while using `List<A>` will limit you to use that type only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on the way you are going to use your parameter in your method. If you are going to enumerate it, then passing `IEnumerable<T>` is a good choice. If you are going to add/remove items, then it should be of `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` or `List<T>` type.

Try not to give your method *more* knowledge, then it needs to fulfill it's responsibilities. But also don't give it *less* knowledge, because it will not be able to fulfill its responsibilities :)

One more sample - should you pass `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` if you need count of items in your method? With list you can use `Count` property. With enumerable you have `Count()` extension method. Correct answer is - pass count of items, if count is all you need.